# Can Keycloak store user data encryted in postgres

Tags: postgresql, security, encryption, oauth, keycloak

I want to use keycloak as openId Connect implementation via docker with a postgres db.
I could not find a resource where it is documented whether keycloak stores user data encrypted. Only passwords seem to be hashed.
Postgres provides pgcrypto as a way to execute encryption and decryption at runtime.
Is there a way to enable crypto for user data with keycloak?

Answer (score 2):

Keycloak provides an option called User Storage SPI 
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_user-storage-spi

 With this, you can build a bridge between keycloak and your DB.
You will have the freedom to store your data in DB as per your convenience and when keycloak invokes the User storage SPI method you will have to return as per keycloak's specifications.

Comment: we tried this approach couldn't accomplish the entire goal since the default entry of keycloak still in plain text.. Is there anyway we can disable the default keycloak jpa entity which is creating a duplicate entries with plain text data?

Comment: Can you clarify further ? keycloak requires its dedicated database to manage it's data. But for a realm when you define the user federation to SPI it does not duplicate the user entries. Keycloak relies on the User-SPI entirely for the user management. Maybe you have different realms where one has the SPI configured and other realms are not using SPI ? and hence you are noticing duplicates ?